# Data augmentation affects convergence speed

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

Data augmentation is surely a great regularization method, and it improves my accuracy on the unseen test set. However, I do not understand why it reduces the convergence speed of the network? I know each epoch takes a longer time to train since image transformations are applied on the fly. But why does it affect the convergence? For my current setup, the network hits a 100% training accuracy after 5 epochs without data augmentation (and clearly overfits) - with data augmentation, it takes 23 epochs to hit 95% training accuracy and never seems to hit 100%.

Any links to research papers or comments on the reasonings behind this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are evaluating accuracy on the train set, right? And it is a mistake...

Without augmentation your network simply overfits. You have a predefined number of images, for instance, 1000, and your network during training can easily memorize dataset labels. And you are evaluating the model on the fixed (not augmented) dataset.

When you are training your network with data augmentation, basically, you are training a model on a dataset of infinite size. You are doing augmentation on the fly, which means that the model "sees" new images every time, and it cannot memorize them perfectly with 100% accuracy. And you are evaluating the model on the augmented (infinite) dataset.

When you train your model with and without augmentation, you evaluate it on the different datasets, so it is not correct to compare their accuracy.

**Piece of advice:**
Do not look at train set accuracy, it is simply misleading when you use augmentations. Instead - evaluate your model on the test set (or validation set), which is not augmented. By doing this - you'll see the real accuracy increase for your model.

P.S. If you want to find out more about image augmentaitons, I really recommend you to check this guide - https://notrocketscience.blog/complete-guide-to-data-augmentation-for-computer-vision/